# What's the word for being passed through a line of armed men to be beaten?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in the movie *Hunger*: http://youtu.be/tprMKFaTRPk (first 30 seconds). Does the punishment that comprises being passed through a line of armed men to be beaten, have a name?

Comment: Though for this particular example it doesn't work particularly well, [onelook](http://www.onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml) usually finds words from descriptions pretty well.

Comment: I couldn't help but picture a certain scene from the movie "Flying High" when I read your question...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called *[running the gantlet/gauntlet](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/run-the-gauntlet.html).*